# Ramifications Of Cross-Object Reference Just For Id?

Tags: apex, soql, bestpractice, performance, dynamic-apex

## The Problem

I see this pattern often and it drives me crazy:

```
Id accountId = someOpportunity.Account.Id;
// just reference AccountId!
```

**OR**

```
List<MyObject__c> records = [SELECT ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE Parent__r.Id = :someId];
// just reference Parent__c!
```

While it may irk me no end, I have no evidence that it is *bad* for any particular reason. So I want to know:

- **Are there any negative side-effects of this anti-pattern to watch out for?**
- **Does it have a performance impact?**
- **Any weird bugs that can be avoided with a direct reference?**

---

**Anecdotal Evidence**

I did once see a related bug, but I'm not sure how reproducible it is... The basic setup was that we had a Master-Detail relationship set up that allowed reparenting. Somehow we ended up with orphan detail records, and a query that looked for `Master__r.Id != null`. The filter returned these orphaned records! Apparently the `Master__r.Id` reference still pointed to the record in the Recycle Bin, but the `Master__c` reference worked as expected. Like I said, no idea if this scenario can even be reproduced, so I won't add it as an answer unless I can work up an MVR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any negative side-effects of this anti-pattern to watch out for?

There's a maximum of 35 child-to-parent references in a query (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_soslsoql.htm)). So, for the majority of queries, it probably never matters, but if you're brushing up against that limit, an easy optimization is to remove references like that.

> Does it have a performance impact?

## CPU Time

There is approximately a 0.001 millisecond CPU penalty every time you navigate a non-null relationship. This was tested over several iterations using varying lengths of relationship chains. In every case, simply adding in the additional reference caused an increase of 1,000 ms per 1,000,000 references navigated consistently.

While this appears small, that means that if you're processing a maximum-sized batch process of 50,000,000 rows will experience an additional 50 seconds of processing *for each time* you use a reference unnecessarily. It's an unnecessary nickel-and-dime charge you can avoid simply by not using it.

## Heap/Memory Usage

There's also approximately a 73 byte difference in heap usage for a non-null reference, because an entire extra object has to be instantiated. At the maximum of 50,000 query rows, and 35 relationships per query, this could result in an extra heap usage of 127,750,000 bytes out of our allowed 6,000,000, 12,000,000, or 36,000,000 bytes of heap (synchronous/asynchronous/email services). This is the *primary* reason why you'd want to avoid using it. 73 bytes is not an insignificant amount of storage when you're using it by the thousands.

## Query Optimization

When you use a reference in a filter, it results in extra planning:

### Relationship Query

[image: Relationship filter]

### Direct Query

[image: Direct filter]

A null scan query (`accountid <> null` vs `account.id <> null`) is faster when you don't use the reference notation. When a table scan is not required, there's no performance difference either way as far as I can tell.

> Any weird bugs that can be avoided with a direct reference?

One typical scenario that gets people quite frequently, particularly in a trigger context, is that references are not automatically populated in Trigger.new and Trigger.old. This means that if you check `Account.Id` instead of `AccountId`, it will be null, and your trigger won't work the way you expect. Therefore, you should prefer to use the lookup field instead of the reference.

Comment: So one microsecond (`μs`)? Interesting tidbit about the child-to-parent references, I hadn't seen that before.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Still figuring out additional differences, lol.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't know if there's anything else I can think of, but I think the heap usage tidbit is the most interesting of all. I'm surprised a simple 18 character Id results in 73 bytes of usage.

Comment: Might be worth adding that you can't get the value in the trigger where you normally would have been able to. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/193784/2995