# Trigger not getting invoked

Tags: apex, trigger

I wanted to write a trigger on the detail object, which checks for duplicate child records and updates the count on the Master field.

I do not see the trigger firing. Here is the code:

```
trigger DuplicateLines on Invce_Lne__c (after insert, After Delete, After Undelete) {

    Set<Id> setIvceIds = new Set<Id>();

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
        for(Invce_Lne__c invceline : Trigger.new)
        {
            setInvceIds.add(invcelne.Invoice__r.Id);
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for(Invce_Lne__c invcelne : Trigger.old){
           setInvceIds.add(invcelne.Invce__r.Id); 
        }
    }

    List<Invce__c> listInvce = [Select Id,name, (select id from Invce_Lns__r) from Invce__c where Id IN :setInvceIds];
    for(Invce__c inv : listInvce)
    {
        inv.Duplicate_Count_for_Invoice_Lines__c = inv.Invce_lns__r.size();
        system.debug(inv.OrderApi__Invoice_lines__r.size());
    }
    update listInvce;
}
```

Comment: [Debug Log Filtering for Apex Classes and Apex Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_debug_log_classes.htm&type=0) please include debugging info in your post.

Answer (score 4):

You have subverted yourself by using `Lookup__r.Id` instead of `Lookup__c`.

The latter field is on the record itself. This field holds the literal `Id` value and will *always* be defined in the trigger context as long as the field is populated.

With the former approach, you are trying to get parent data, and **[parent data is not available in the trigger context](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/120577/2995)**.

So just change `Invoice__r.Id` (and `Invce__r.Id`) to use the `__c` field directly on the trigger records.

Also somewhat relevant: [Ramifications Of Cross-Object Reference Just For Id?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/155739/2995)

Comment: If I change setInvceIds.add(invcelne.Invoice__r.Id); with setInvceIds.add(invcelne.Invoice__c.Id);, will that work?? I was receiving error when I tried that. May be I am not completely sure about this

Comment: @user I didn't say replace `__r.Id` with `__c.Id`. I said replace `__r.Id` with `__c`.

Comment: Oops yeah got it..