# Error on Callout: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, callout

I was hoping I could get assistance with this error I'm receiving when my Apex classes are running.

> Failed    First error: Attempt to de-reference a null object

I couldn't find a specific object that would be null in my code and wasn't sure how I could trace it to a line in my code.

In summary I have an active process builder that sends variables to an invokable method, which then runs another class to call out to an external API.

HELPER

```
global class InfluitiveEventsAPIHelper {
    @InvocableMethod
    //Method that accepts the ContactIDs from Process Builder and process through Influitive's API
    global static void updateContactStateInfo(List<EventsRequest > eventRequest) {
        Id recordId= eventRequest[0].recordId;
        String event_type= eventRequest[0].event_type;
        String points= eventRequest[0].points;
        String stagecode= eventRequest[0].stagecode;

        Contact con = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id=: recordId];
        System.debug('updateContactStateInfo, con=' + con);
        Influitive_EventsAPI_Post.postEvent(con.Id, points, event_type, stagecode);

    }

    global class EventsRequest {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        global ID recordId;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        global String event_type;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        global String points;

        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        global String stagecode;

    }
}
```

CALLOUT CLASS

```
global class Influitive_EventsAPI_Post {

    public static HttpCalloutMock mock = null; // this is populated while call is from test class

    public class Message {
        public Event event;  // Event information

    }

    //Event information
    public class Event{
        public Contact contact;
        public String points;
        public String type;
        public Stage stage;

    }

    public class Contact {
        public String id;
    }

    public class Stage {
        public String code;
    }

    // this method convert the message object to the JSON string which is used to send information
    // to the Influitive's referral API in a post request
    private static String toJsonString(Message m) {
        return JSON.serializePretty(m.event);
    }    

    /**
     * it will send the updated event information to the Influitive API.
     **/
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void postEvent(Id objectId, String points, String type, String stagecode) {

        Event e = new Event();

        e.contact.id = objectId;
        e.points = points;
        e.type = type;
        e.stage.code = stagecode;

        //retrive Authorization and X Org ID from Custom settings.
        ReferralSettings__c authSettings = ReferralSettings__c.getValues('Authorization');
        ReferralSettings__c xOrgIdSettings = ReferralSettings__c.getValues('X_ORG_ID');

        System.debug('authSettings =' + authSettings  + 'xOrgIdSettings=' + xOrgIdSettings );

        // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (PUT) as well as the endpoint  
        String url='https://api.influitive.com/events';
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        //req.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override","POST");
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authSettings.Value__c);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('X_ORG_ID', xOrgIdSettings.Value__c);



        Message m = new Message();
        m.event = e;
        System.debug(m);



        String body = toJsonString(m);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(body);
        System.debug('this is the body');
        System.debug(body);

        HttpResponse res = null;

        if (Test.isRunningTest() && (mock!=null)) {
           res = mock.respond(req);
        } else {
            res = h.send(req);
        }

        System.debug('Response: '+ res.getBody());
        System.debug('Response: '+ res.getStatusCode());
        String sInteger = String.valueOf(res.getStatusCode());

       // Add notes to contact

        note n = new note();
        n.parentId= objectId; //Id of the object for which you want to add this note
        n.body=sInteger + url + authSettings.Value__c + xOrgIdSettings.Value__c; // body of the note. this should be populated from the notes field that you have shown in the screenshot
        n.title = 'Response from Influitive API at ' + datetime.now(); // the title of the note
        n.isPrivate=false;  // if private it will be visible only for the owner and any user with modify all permission
        insert n; //insert the record

    }
}
```

TRACE

> System.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to de-reference a null object
>
> Class.Influitive_EventsAPI_Post.postEvent: line 47, column 1

This is line 47 of my code:

```
e.contact.id = objectId;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to clarify which line is 47, as it appears to be a line which could not throw this error: `ReferralSettings__c authSettings = ReferralSettings__c.getValues('Authorization');`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the lookup using the field. Its API Name is `ContactId`.

```
e.ContactId = objectId;
```

When you use `e.Contact.Id` instead, what you are doing is first retrieving `e.Contact`, then trying to set a value on it. That wouldn't work for setting the relationship even if this related record weren't null. Here's an equivalent version of what you currently have:

```
Event e = new Event();
Contact relatedContact = e.Contact; // this value is null
relatedContact.Id = someValue; // here you try to de-reference null.Id
```

See also:

- [Ramifications Of Cross-Object Reference Just For Id?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/155739/2995)
- [Set Relationship Via Name Pointing Field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/133556/2995)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue as I wasn't instantiating the nested objects.

this did the trick:

```
//Event information
public class Event{
    public Contact contact = new Contact();
    public String points;
    public String type;
    public Stage stage = new Stage();

}
```